# Name check during registration - python

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a mini python project for registering and checking validation of name, mail, username, etc. btw, I used regex for most times. in the name validation function, I don't really know the issue, but its output is:
[The output should write that a problem has occurred (don't look at my writing issues :D) and then show what is the actual problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlbHI.png)

This is the code:

```
import re

def register():
  # all registering and checking proccess.
  name = input('Name: ')
  username = input('Username: ')
  password = input('Please select password: ')
  mail = input('Mail: ')
  mail_check_return = mail_check(mail)
  password_check_return = password_check(password)
  name_check_return = name_check(name)

  if password_check_return == True and name_check_return == True and len(username) > 1 and 
mail_check_return == True:
    print(f'{name}, you have been registerd sucsessfully!')
  else:

    print('\na problem has occurred!')
    if mail_check_return == False:
      print('The entered mail is invalid.')

    if password_check_return != True:
      print(password_check_return)

    if len(username) <= 1:
      print('The entered username is invaild.')

    register()
  return name, username, mail

def menu():
  print('Hello! what do you want to do?')
  name, username, mail = register()

def match(entered_password, entered_username):
  pass
  # not finished.

def mail_check(mail_c):
  if '@' in mail_c and len(mail_c) > 6:
    return True
  else:
    return False

def password_check(password):
  if len(password) >= 6:
    if re.search('[0-9]', password):      
      if re.search('[A-Za-z]', password):
        return True
      else:
        return 'Your password must contain numbers.'
    else:
      return 'Your password must contain english characters.'
  else:
    return 'Your password must contain at least 6 characters.'

def name_check(name):
  if len(name) <= 2:
    if re.search('[0-9]', name):
      return 'Your name can\'t contain numbers!'
    else:
      if re.search('[A-Za-z]', name):
        return True
      else:
        return 'The name is invalid.'

def match(entered_password, entered_username):
  pass

def sign_in(username): # 4 lined to un(note). VVV

  # not finished.
   pass
menu()
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first judgement for name length should be wrong, and it return None !!!

```py
def name_check(name):
  if len(name) <= 2:    # <<<------- Here, name should greater than 2, return None
    if re.search('[0-9]', name):
      return 'Your name can\'t contain numbers!'
    else:
      if re.search('[A-Za-z]', name):
        return True
      else:
        return 'The name is invalid.'
```